# How can I make a free/paid version of my Android application?

Tags: android

I am about to release my application for the Android market, but I would like to make 2 versions. One with ads; one without. Not only must the app be able to tell that it's been paid for, so it knows not to show ads, but there needs to be 2 versions on the market.

I have searched Google and Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to find any concrete solutions. Some people have suggested separate apk's, shared libraries (I'm not even familiar with this method), etc etc. I was just wondering if anyone with experience in the field could shed some light on the situation, how they did it personally and what was successful or not.

Comment: I think you should upload 2 differend apks to the store. One free, one paid.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the issue is? make one with ads, make one without, upload them under different names, done. The only thing that might need a braincycle or 2 is how to keep them easy updated. But I'd   just make it 1 project, switch a setting, compile, done?

Comment: ah, when you put it like that, that is probably easier. i was probably looking into it a little bit.. i can settle with the harder updating. thanks :)
edit: but.. lets say i have a link in the free version to the paid version. what happens if they buy it? how can i make it overwrite the old 1 while keeping all data intact etc

Comment: i think i found a solution: http://www.yoki.org/2010/07/31/creating-a-freepaid-app-pair-for-the-android-market/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it as 2 different apps. Use something such as AdMob for the free one. And no AdMob for the other paid one.

Comment: but then if they install the paid version, wont they have 2 separate versions on their device?

Comment: Are you talking about something like "In-App Purchases" that remove ads? I know thats what they're called on IOS